# VBA Instr function on 100K+ records

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have 100.000 records/rows with 17 columns. One of these columns needs to be checked to output either a 1 or 0 to the next column. For this I use a loop with the Instr function, but after 10 mins it still isn't outputting anything on my machine and I believe the code is too intensive or slow running it row for row.

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("F:F")

For Each cell In rng
    TicketType = cell
    If InStr(1, TicketType, "locker", 1) > 0 Then
        cell.Offset(0, 1) = 1
    Else
        cell.Offset(0, 1) = 0
    End If
Next
```

There are only 100 TicketTypes to check however, and based on the names of these TicketTypes it should output a 1 or 0 (match or not). So I was thinking, maybe there is a way to sort the entire table, run through it to see which categories there are, store their vertical ranges, run a check and then output +-10.000 rows at once? I noticed this is instant, so I believe it's really the Instr function that is the bottleneck.

Comment: You could do this with a formula... or with a Variant array, it'd be quicker than looping cell-by-cell, which is the real issue.

Comment: @BigBen, thoughts on `application.ScreenUpdating = false` in this case?

Comment: Eh .. really should avoid looping cell-by-cell, that's the problem.

Comment: Could you elaborate which formula or what you mean with variant array? Is storing and manipulating the range into an array faster because you then work from memory?

Comment: Yes that's it and that's the way go to, though note that your code is currently running through a million cells which is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Variant array approach**

As mentioned by BigBen it's faster than looping through each cell by means of VBA.

```
Sub VariantArray()
With Sheet1

'~~> Set you relevant range here
    Dim lastRow As Long, rng As Range
    lastRow = .Range("F" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("F1:F" & lastRow)

'~~> create a one based 2-dim datafield array
     Dim myArray As Variant
     myArray = rng

'~~> check TicketType
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(myArray)
        myArray(i, 1) = IIf(InStr(1, myArray(i, 1), "locker", 1) > 0, 1, 0)
    Next i

    '~~> fill target with array values
    rng.Offset(0, 1) = myArray

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks everybody for all the ideas. In the end I went with T.M.'s solution and it does 100K records in only... 1 sec! Maybe I forgot to mention, but the the TicketType is not exactly corresponding to the word locker, but it might be somewhere in there and I had to find out which ones. So this was easiest to adapt to my use case.

Comment: all other solutions run in less than 1 second. but … there wll last only one!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Dim rng As Range, f
With ActiveSheet
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(.Columns("F"), .UsedRange)
    f = "=--NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(""locker""," & rng(1).Address(False, False) & ")))"
    Debug.Print f
    rng.Offset(0, 1).Formula = f
    rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

you could try filtering:

```
With Worksheets("actualSheetName") '<-- change "actualSheetName" to your actual sheet name
    With .Range("F1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))
        .Offset(, 1).Value = 0
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*locker*"

        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(, 1) = 1
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

Comment: avoids loops, direct & fast +)

Comment: @T.M., yes but all given solutions are very fast

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by BigBen, a far better solution is the usage of a worksheet function, like `Find.All()` (at least that how I think it's called). If it finds something, it gives a number, else it gives an error. You might turn this into an interesting formula like this:

```
=IF(IF.ERR(FIND.ALL("locker";A2);0)=0;0;1)
```